# linux: shorter 'host' command output

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, host, dig

I'm using dns to manage my virtual hosts. In order to do so I query my nameserver with the host command for certain values I need. For example:

```
> host -t txt mycl1.vz
mycl1.vz.myserver.de descriptive text "1026"
```

but I only need `1026` as answer without the chatter. Currently I'm using sed to remove it like:

```
| sed -e 's/.*descriptive text "\(.*\)"/\1/'
```

but this seems a little "unstable" and I wonder if there isn't some command which would give me the plain output in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`dig(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) with the `+short` flag instead:

```
$ host -t txt google.com
google.com descriptive text "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all"

$ dig -t txt google.com +short
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all"
```

If you want to remove the quotes, just filter the output through `sed`:

```
$ dig -t txt google.com +short | sed 's/"//g'
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Now I have still to remove the quotes.

Comment: _"How about reverse PTR records"_ you might ask? `dig` has the "-x" argument for that, nowadays: `dig +short -x 1.1.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be dig as dawud pointed out. If you stick with 'host', you could replace sed with:

```
cut -d \" -f 2
```

Comment: Thanks. Good shortcut. But I need it for A records, too.

Comment: Host has a variable format output. One more reason to use dig for such operations :) (For example cut -d " " -f 4  for A records and host)